# MEAN Stack, where to manipule/get data best? frontend/backend?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-manipulation

I am using mean stack, and I have a Backend where I have my data (MongoDB) and where I am doing data manipulation/retrieving and API middleware+routing.
I am also using a frontend to retrieve data by Http Services...
I get the data always as arrays of JSON objects..

Now my question is, what is the best way to retrieve and manipulate data? Should I do this in general as early as possible, which means in the backend already, and query a most selective amount of data from mongodb, or should I just get all data and do complicated data manipulation with javascript in angular, as it suits me for different apps?

Because at the moment, I am using the backend to prepare the data up in a certain format for ngx-charts, but I could do this in the HttpClient in Angular as well... I would just have to pass all the data and format it in angular javascript code... 
BUt later on, I would have to fit the data for other apps (or widgets) not just charts, etc.. so I would have to create each a different route for retrieving the different data for each of my widgets and do the data formatting in mongodb aggregation framework... or is it better to get all data at once and fit them later for different widgets in angular javascript?

what do you think is the general (or best) approach?? any suggestions from experienced programmers thus far?

Comment: Which of the two formats is bigger? How much time does it take to convert? Do multiple clients get the same dataset? The cool thing about NodeJS is that you just write the function in Javascript, and you can easily try out both ways and do performance assessments

Comment: well, if I pass just all the data, its quite bigger than the selection of course. If do the data prep up in mongodb aggregation framework, its a little fiddle around but you can pass e.g an ID value and it gets the correct data...So this is also for different clients. In general, its not for multiple clients. I think the data manipulation in angular is more complicated and bigger code. Because it's asynchronous, you would also have to do data manipulation everytime inside the http.get method of Angular HttpClient as far as I understand.

Comment: from a performance standpoint of view, I'm not sure which is better, doing a lot of queries to the database with small amount of data to return, or return all data kind of once and do the data manipulation in the frontend...

Comment: Mongodb is heavily optimized to do queries, and your server is robably more performant than the average client. Additionally more data takes longer to get transfered to the client

Comment: @Jonas W I would agree with you, and mostly I think, my data is kind of private data for a single client, as I have mostly a client-based dashboard-like application...